# Where is mongodb source code in pentaho dpi-5.3 (kettle)?

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

Here is my problem. I need to use the functions of mongodb defined in kettle source code. As in kettle-5.3 transformation steps, it supports mongodb input and output(in big data).  I download the 5.3 version from github, [github link](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/tree/5.3).  But I can not find the source file of mongodb in the path of "\pentaho-kettle-5.3\engine\src\org\pentaho\di\trans\steps\". Actually, all the steps can be found here.

Could anyone help me find the mongodb files?

And my target is to customize the mongodb input step by using Metadata Injection to rewrite the .ktr file. In this way, users can give the parameters(define the name of the data in mongodb) from outside, such as a web page. Is there any wrong with this idea?

Any suggestion is appreciated!! Thanks!!!

Comment: i am using cassandra, and cassandra input and output step only works with PDI 4.8 their is some issue with 5.1 onwards version PDI in case of cassandra and those are open bugs, so i advise to go with little older version, go with 5.2 or 5.1 and check mongodb steps are their and if it is their then it is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think the sources you need can be found in here:

https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-mongodb-plugin

The mongo DB steps are a separate plugin, not included in Kettle core.

Comment: That's right !! Latest version of kettle does not support Mongodb well. Your answer helps me a lot!